# Is there a one-to-one relationship between bits and transistors?

Tags: hardware

I am a beginning student of computer science trying to understand hardware architecture.

I am wondering if 1 bit is always equal to 1 transistor. If not, what is the relationship between bits and transistors? How are bits implemented at the hardware (transistor) level?

As far as I understand, data is stored as a sequence of bits, and components like RAM consist of transistors, so it seems like each of those bits would be stored in a transistor.

Comment: No. Apples and Oranges. You can't compare bits to transistors. A single transistor can't store anything. Recommended material: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyznrdDSSGM&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU

Comment: Related: [Wikipedia: DRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory) Most importantly, though: *It does not matter.* Except for *very* special environments, you should never have to worry about these details, as they are abstracted away by the architecture and operaring system.

Comment: A standard light switch is 1 bit of information - it's "on" or "off", 1 or 0.  But this comparison is no more meaningful than asking whether a transistor - which may be "on" or "off" -- is 1 bit.  You could, if so inclined, design a circuit where the on/off state of a single transistor conveyed 1 bit of data - we tend to call those "I/O lines".  For memory, there are better choices, for example various flip-flops.

Answer (score 6):

#### No, not exactly, and not even close except for a special case or 2

A bit is an abstract unit of information.

A transistor is a physical thing, a current (BJT) or voltage-controlled (FET) switch, more or less.  Modern digital logic uses FETs (CMOS), so voltage-controlled.

In [DRAM, a transistor **and a capacitor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Principles_of_operation) can temporarily store a bit (when used as part of a DRAM array with other transistors for addressing and so on).

Or a single transistor plus a resistor can ([in RTL logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic#RTL_inverter)) implement a NOT gate which flips 1 bit.  (A CMOS NOT gate [takes 2 transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS).)

**In general no, it's not sensible to say that a transistor is a bit**.  If you're talking about how many transistors are needed to *implement* a cache or register file with a given capacity, then it becomes relevant that an SRAM cell usually consists of 6 or more transistors. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory#Design).  Using more than 6 can help it [work more stably at low voltages](https://www.realworldtech.com/near-threshold-voltage/), saving power.  (Modern CPUs have such tiny transistors that they're more limited by power density than number of transistors. See http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ - it's a *very* good overview of CPU-architecture stuff, but at a higher level than individual transistors.)

When not part of a whole array of memory, a bit might be stored by a flip-flop / latch made of multiple transistors to implement clock, set/reset, and input, depending on [what type of flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

That wikipedia link shows some flip-flop designs.  **A bit is the state of voltages on those transistors, not the transistors themselves.**  Or you can say that the flip-flop has a storage capacity of 1 bit.